# github ssh key saving to location I can't find

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am running ssh-keygen in git bash

Your identification has been saved in /h//.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /h//.ssh/id_rsa.pub

I search through my home directory which I believe is my username Users/mingomango and have searched other places but nothing.

How can I find where it's going?

I tried searching through my users and home directory and found nothing. When I do another ssh-keygen is gives me an option to overwrite the files so it's gotta be somewhere right?

Comment: Outside of git-bash lookup `h:\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` and `h:\.ssh\id_rsa`

Comment: Are you including hidden files and directories in your search? `.ssh` is hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try `find` command.

```
find -L / -type f -name 'id_rsa*' 2>/dev/null
```

This command will find all files name id_rsa in your computer

#### Explanation:

`-L` follow links

`/`  scan starting from root directory

`-type f` scan only files

`-name 'id_rsa*'` scan files with suffix `id_rsa`

`2>/dev/null` ignore all error messages